# Setting image for a cell if index.row is in my array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that has 100 rows. What I'd like to do is set an image for the row if the index of the row is in my array that I have. What I've found is that it only sets the image for the first number in the array. So, in this example, I have [2,3,4,5] in my array. The result is that it is setting the image for the row where index = 2. Rather than for all the numbers. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
var completedWorkoutsArray = [2,3,4,5]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")! //1.
    let text = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = text


    for i in completedWorkoutsArray {
        if(indexPath.row == i) {
            let image: UIImage = checkmark!
            cell.imageView!.image = image
        }
        else
        {
            let image: UIImage = redX!
            cell.imageView!.image = image
        }
    }

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")!
    let text = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = text

    let image = completedWorkoutsArray.contains(indexPath.row) ? checkmark : redX
    cell.imageView.image = image

    return cell
}
```

Your code fails because it loops through all values in the array. It sets the image each and every time. The last image set is the one you see.